# These Buffer.from toString('base64') doesn't convert properly - what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, base64

### Check this nodejs on runkit:

https://runkit.com/hollerith/5a726441d9a9770013dcce93

Having copypasta numerous sources came up with ways of grabbing this specific image and converting it to a base64 encoded data uri.

```js
var requestBase64 = require('base64-img').requestBase64;
var request = require('request');
var got = require("got");

url = 'http://c1.staticflickr.com/2/1442/26088546654_d034205325_n.jpg';

response = await got(url);
const buf = Buffer.from(response.body, 'binary');
const data = buf.toString('base64');
console.log(`data:image/jpeg;base64,${data}`);

requestBase64(url, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log(body);
});

request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  const buf = Buffer.from(body, 'binary');
  const data = buf.toString('base64');
  console.log(`data:image/jpeg;base64,${data}`);
});
```

### Only requestBase64 works: why don't the others?

Comment: what are "the others" - in what way do they "not work"?

Comment: not work meaning their output is not a base64 encoding the datauri doesn't display? The correct one displays the original image...? You can run it on runkit and see - this is server side node so the snippet won't work

Comment: Yes, I see - so, `request` and `got` get the same result as each other, so, they both get it "wrong" in the exact same way - converting the first 80 or so characters from base64 to binary should help you see where they are going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `{encoding: null}` to `request` and it returns the same data as requestBase64.

```
request(url, {encoding: null}, function (error, response, body) {
  const buf2 = Buffer.from(body, 'binary');
  const data2 = buf2.toString('base64');
  console.log(`data:image/jpeg;base64,${data2}`);
});
```

Similary for `got` library you can pass in encoding.

```
response = await got(url, { encoding: null });
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. They all produce valid datauri now. I need to figure out what is going on there with the default encoding in these request wrappers.

Comment: AFAIK the default is utf8, that's why they were different.